AWS EMR - reading multiple "zip" files from S3 bucket returns Your key is too long
In my daily job I use EMR to process large amount of data. This data are stored in CSV files on S3 bucket. The idea I had was to try to process ziped csv files instead of plain csv.
In Hive app I use this declaration:
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE collection.stg_events_parq(sequence String, Timestampval string, frames int, point String, startTime String, SerialNumber string, metertype string, currentfile string, data_date string, hour string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES 
('separatorChar'=';')
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://useast1-dataload-perc/col2/perc_archive/file_data_archive/Peter'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'compression.codec'='org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec'
);

When executing a query that reads from this table I get the below exception:
Caused by: com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Your key is too long (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: KeyTooLongError; Request ID: B9MG9V5NAJKS44CZ; S3 Extended Request ID: jaO7x9Pd5OMZtR5MmpdUD5wOjNIRnPouo6flFZFU+CU/saOba6ZP9Ley1xxznrvAt/zPEzmcW+4=; Proxy: null), S3 Extended Request ID: jaO7x9Pd5OMZtR5MmpdUD5wOjNIRnPouo6flFZFU+CU/saOba6ZP9Ley1xxznrvAt/zPEzmcW+4=
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1879)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleServiceErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1418)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1387)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1157)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:814)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:781)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:755)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:715)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:697)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:561)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:541)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5520)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5467)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.initiateMultipartUpload(AmazonS3Client.java:3768)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.call.InitiateMultipartUploadCall.perform(InitiateMultipartUploadCall.java:27)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.call.InitiateMultipartUploadCall.perform(InitiateMultipartUploadCall.java:13)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.executor.GlobalS3Executor$CallPerformer.call(GlobalS3Executor.java:114)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.executor.GlobalS3Executor.execute(GlobalS3Executor.java:141)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.AmazonS3LiteClient.invoke(AmazonS3LiteClient.java:196)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.AmazonS3LiteClient.invoke(AmazonS3LiteClient.java:191)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.AmazonS3LiteClient.initiateMultipartUpload(AmazonS3LiteClient.java:147)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:166)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:158)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:96)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:362)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.initiateMultipartUpload(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.MultipartUploadOutputStream.ensureMultipartUploadIsInitiated(MultipartUploadOutputStream.java:559)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.MultipartUploadOutputStream.uploadSinglePartWithMultipartUpload(MultipartUploadOutputStream.java:406)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.MultipartUploadOutputStream.doMultiPartUpload(MultipartUploadOutputStream.java:443)
    ... 34 more
]], Vertex did not succeed due to OWN_TASK_FAILURE, failedTasks:1 killedTasks:188, Vertex vertex_1721283681941_0004_5_02 [Reducer 3] killed/failed due to:OWN_TASK_FAILURE]DAG did not succeed due to VERTEX_FAILURE. failedVertices:1 killedVertices:0

Has anyone here faced a similar issue?
I've checked that the length of my file names doesn't exceed 300 characters. I've also verified that all 3,412 zip files are not corrupted.
Any ideas on what could be causing the problem?
configuration of my EMR:
Primary 1x r5.2xlarge
Core 4x r5.24xlarge
Hadoop 3.3.6
Hive 3.1.3
Thank you
Peter
